# Solving ODEs python with non-independent funcitons python

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, ode

I'm trying to plot a multi-equation ODE from [this paper](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/2cz4q2jq) and I'm having trouble figuring out how to express the dependencies between the functions. I.e, in **3.1**, it uses both **z1** and **z2**. Aswell as using its own precious state **x**. I've checked the Scipy documentation but they don't seem to express the functionality that I'm trying to achieve.

How do I express I.e equation **3.1** with Scipy?

[image]

Comment: What is the term `delta(t-td)y` meant to express? Is it really meant to be a Dirac delta, or, as you seem to imply, a delayed evaluation? `scipy` does not have DDE solvers, one could rig one using the solve_ivp stepper classes. Eq. 3.3 is redundant.

Comment: The delta is meant as a dirac delta, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Then you can simulate it via a delta approximation, or implement the jump externally by integrating first to `t=td`, then `x_plus - x_minus = -lambda*x_minus` or perhaps better, using the midpoint `x_plus - x_minus =-0.5*lambda*(x_plus + x_minus)`, the same for `y`, then restart the integration with the plus values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement a system ODE function

```
def sys(t,u):
    x,y,z1,z2 = u
    v1 = z1/(p1*z2)-1
    v2 = 1-y/p6
    return p0*v1, p2*(x/p3-1)+p4*v1, p7*z1*v2, (p7-p5*z2/z1)*z2*v2

#integrate to jump
sol1 = solve_ivp(sys,(t0,td),u0,**options)
# implement the jump
x,y,z1,z2 = sol1.y[:,-1]
fac = (2-λ)/(2+λ); 
x*=fac; y*=fac
ud = [x,y,z1,z2]
# restart integration
sol2 = solve_ivp(sys,(td,tf),ud,**options)
```

`options` is a dictionary for the method, tolerances, etc., see documentation. Then evaluate the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Lutz Lehmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3088138/lutz-lehmann), I solved it based on your answer.
On a side note, equation **3.3** isn't redundant, I should have clarified that it's a term for the amount of pure silver in each coin. So it's an independent value (weird way of defining it in the paper, I agree).

Here is the solution I ended up using:

```
def dSdt(t,S):
x,y,z1,z2,z1_z2 = S

xn = p0*((z1_z2/p1)-1)

yn = p2*((x/p3)-1) + p4*((z1_z2/p1)-1) 

z1n = p7*z1*(1-(y/p6))

z2n = z2*(1-(y/p6))*(p7-p5*z1_z2)

z1_z2n = p5*(1-(y/p6))

return [xn,yn,z1n,z2n,z1_z2n]

# Before td
t1 = np.linspace(t0,395,abs(t0)+395,dtype=int)
S0_1 = [x_t0,y_t0,z1_t0,z2_t0,z1_div_z2_t0]
sol1 = odeint(dSdt,y0=S0_1,t=t1,tfirst=True)

# Handle division at td
sol1[-1][0] *= λ 
sol1[-1][1] *= λ
S0_2 = sol1.T[:,-1]

# After td
t2 = np.linspace(start=396,stop=500,num=500-396,dtype=int)
sol2 = odeint(dSdt,y0=S0_2,t=t2,tfirst=True)
sol= np.concatenate((sol1,sol2))
t = np.concatenate((t1,t2))
```

Comment: But you can check, `z1_z2` and `z1/z2` should always have the same value (up to error tolerance, probably better). The reduction in this form is closer to the text, but only compatible with the formulas if one allows the `λ` to be different there. This only really matters if one replaces the deltas with some weight-one needle peaks.